# How to create a popup menu by pressing a button in react native

Tags: android, react-native, drop-down-menu, model, popup

I am noob I want to create a popup as shown in the image below when pressing a button. I tried several things but failed.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native-options-menu is a pretty good lib to do this.

https://github.com/izzisolomon/react-native-options-menu

```
npm install react-native-options-menu --save

//use it like so or refer to docs in github link about
<OptionsMenu 
            customButton={(
                <View style={styles.optionsMenu}>
                <SimpleLineIcons 
                    name="options-vertical"
                    size={26}
                    color={Colors.tabIconDefault}/>
                </View>
            )}
            destructiveIndex={1}
            options={buttons.names}
            actions={buttons.actions}/>
```